# Survey Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create survey Application.
I have Class Survey with questions as follow.

```
Class Survey
{ string SurveyID {get;set;}
  List<QuestionList> {get;set;}
}

Class Questions
{
 string QuestionID {get;set;}
  string text {get;set;}
  string type {get;set;}
  string nextQuestion {get;set;}
  List<Option> {get;set;}
}
class Option
{
   string Id {get;set;}
   string text {get;set;}
   string nextQuestionID {get;set;}
}
```

Now, I have Questions filled in above class.
Just want to Display Survey in MVC.

so how should I create view?.
It should display Next Button and at last Question it should Finish.
Also, we are required to store Answers.

Should I Post form every time there is a click on Next?

Please help. Also if possible I would like to see some examples which achieve this kind of functionality.

Comment: Sounds like you want a wizard. Search for how to make a Wizard in MVC

Comment: Not related to your question, but I think `List<QuestionList> {get;set;}` should be `List<Questions> {get;set;}`. And you should not Name class in plural, so your class should be named `Question`.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with GraemeMiller. The best way would be to use some wizard. And push all your questions in wizard steps. You can visit: http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples to find more about jquery wizards.